# How do I get a token to use Google Cloud (Container Engine JSON API)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I just want to create an `OAuth token` that I can use when accessing the [Container Engine](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/) service. But the docs are hopeless in this regard.

Could somebody explain how to generate a token? Every other REST service I've ever used gives me a way of clicking a button and obtaining a token.

**NOTE:** Must not require installing any proprietary software, e.g. the Google SDK.

Answer (score 0):

omg, that was so painful to discover. But eventually I fumbled into this:

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=projectId

(replace `projectId` with the value for your setup)

which lets you generate an API key.